# I just need to get the highest paid employee per city

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to get a new view where I can display ONE record for the highest paid employee in each store.

Output (DESIRED)
Showing the TOP paid employee in each store
STORE_ID - 1 has no employees so it isnt on the report

```
ENAME   JOB         STORE_ID    MAX(SAL)    CITY
ALLEN   SALESMAN    2           1600        New York City
KING    PRESIDENT   3           5000        Chicago
SCOTT   ANALYST     4           3000        Philadelphia
```

ACTUAL OUTPUT

```
ENAME   JOB STORE_ID    MAX(SAL)    CITY
ALLEN   SALESMAN    2   1600    New York City
TURNER  SALESMAN    2   1500    New York City
WARD    SALESMAN    2   1250    New York City
MARTIN  SALESMAN    2   1250    New York City
KING    PRESIDENT   3   5000    Chicago
BLAKE   MANAGER 3   2850    Chicago
CLARK   MANAGER 3   2450    Chicago
SCOTT   ANALYST 4   3000    Philadelphia
FORD    ANALYST 4   3000    Philadelphia
JONES   MANAGER 4   2975    Philadelphia
MILLER  CLERK   4   1300    Philadelphia
ADAMS   CLERK   4   1100    Philadelphia
JAMES   CLERK   4   950 Philadelphia
SMITH   CLERK   4   800 Philadelphia
```

I can only use SELECT, GROUP BY, HAVING, ORDER BY, INNER JOIN (or other types of JOINS). I can't use partition, WITH

This QUERY does produce the rows necessary but it contains every one else (in addition to the highest paid one)

DDL FOR STORES

```
CREATE TABLE  "STORES" 
   (    "STORE_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CITY" VARCHAR2(50), 
     PRIMARY KEY ("STORE_ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )
/
```

DDL FOR EMPLOYEES

```
CREATE TABLE  "EMPLOYEES" 
   (    "EMPNO" NUMBER(4,0), 
    "ENAME" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "JOB" VARCHAR2(9), 
    "HIREDATE" DATE, 
    "SAL" NUMBER(7,2), 
    "COMM" NUMBER(7,2), 
    "STORE_ID" NUMBER
   )
/

CREATE INDEX  "EMP_NAME_IDEX" ON  "EMPLOYEES" ("ENAME")
/

CREATE INDEX  "EMP_NAME_JOB_DATE_IDX" ON  "EMPLOYEES" ("ENAME", "JOB", "HIREDATE")
/
```

the first question was about bad SQL syntax. This one is trying to find the highest paid employee in each store

Comment: share the query you have written

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I don't understand why my group by is failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53789781/i-dont-understand-why-my-group-by-is-failing)

Comment: "I am trying to get a new view where I can display the record for the highest paid employee in each store." is an excerpt from the previous question.

Comment: Can you share the query that produces that result?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `rank` window function to rank the employees per store by their salary and then take just the top one:

```
SELECT t.ename, t.job, t.sal, t.city
FROM   (SELECT e.ename, e.job, e.sal, s.city,
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY e.store_id ORDER BY s.sal DESC) AS rk
        FROM   employees e
        JOIN   stores s on e.store_id = s.store_id) t
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has nice extensions to the `group by` aggregation functions that can help:

```
select max(e.ename) keep (dense_rank first order by e.sal desc) as ename,
       max(e.job) keep (dense_rank first order by e.sal desc) as ejob,
       s.store_id,
       max(e.sal) as sal
       s.city
from employee e join
     stores s
     on e.store_id = s.store_id
group by s.store_id, s.city;
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below using subquery

```
select e.ENAME,t1.STORE_ID,t1.sal,s.CITY from (
 SELECT  MAX(e.SAL) sal,
 e.STORE_ID FROM EMPLOYEES e    
 GROUP BY e.STORE_ID
       ) t1 join EMPLOYEES e on t1.STORE_ID =e.STORE_ID  and e.sal=t1.sal
            join STORES  s on t1.STORE_ID =s.STORE_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

this one  will work:

```
select * from (select e.ename,e.job,s.store_id,s.sal,s.city,
rank() over (partition by s.store_id order by s.sal desc) rnk 
from
employee e ,stores s
where e.store_id=s.store_id)
where rnk=1;
```

Comment: this is the same answer the teacher had on the answer key. Can you please explain it?